# Formatting data using vb and excel

Tags: vb.net, excel

This may sound very simple, but I need some help with it.

I am using VB to create an excel file and doing some searches from another text file. I have as a result a column (A1 to A4) in excel with the following data:

```
H'4404
H'5712
H'5129
H'F112
```

What I need is somehow using VB, instruct excel to show only the numbers read backwards i.e like the following in A1 cell:

```
404421759215211
```

Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Excel VBA has the `VBA.StrReverse()` function but it is possibly simpler to do this from VB.NET. This [dotnetperls](http://www.dotnetperls.com/reverse-string-vbnet) page shows how to replicate this function. (There are other ways to do this - LINQ for example.)

So you need to reverse the strings, [Join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.join.aspx) them to create a single string, then `Replace` the H'. You could replace the H' first if you prefer.

I think you should attempt this yourself and then you'll be able to come back with some code if you struggle.

Answer (score 0):

I would iterate through the cells, and take each value, split it, and concatenate it as text to a variable, which gets written at the end eg.

```
Dim cell As Range
Dim cellRange As Range
Dim delim As String
Dim bob As String

Set cellRange = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A4")
delim = "'"
For Each cell In cellRange
    bob = bob + Split(cell.Text, delim)(1)
Next
range("B1").value=bob
```